# Задача из олимпиады. Задача Бахгольда

Tags: php, java, c++, математика, олимпиада

Задача Бахгольда формулируется очень просто. Дано целое положительное число n. Требуется представить его в виде суммы максимального количества простых слагаемых. Известно, что представление в виде суммы простых существует для всех целых положительных чисел, больших 1.

Напомним, целое положительное число k называется простым, если оно больше 1 и у него ровно два целых положительных делителя — 1 и k.

Comment: Вопрос заключается в чём?

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку число 1 простым не считается, для четного числа максимальное количество простых слагаемых получится при взятии N/2 двоек.

Для нечетного - одна тройка и (N-3)/2 двоек.

*По-моему, так... (c) Пух*

Answer (score 1):

js, на других языках аналогично

```
x = 7;
if ( x%2 == 0 ) {
    a = x/2;
    out = "Сумму можно составить из числе 2, взятых " + a +" раз.";
} else {
    a = Math.floor(x/2) - 1;
    out = "Сумму можно составить из числе 2, взятых " + a +" раз и числа 3";
}
out
```